# Security for 3G/Wireless Broadband connection

Tags: wireless-networking, broadband

How secure do we think broadband wireless is?  Should I be willing to do online banking over a mobile connection?  I assume that it's more secure than, say, WEP, but I'd love to be pointed towards any information about how easy cellular connections are to crack.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it doesn't matter how easy cell. connections are to crack because you are always using SSL/TLS encryption over that, and that hasn't been cracked yet. Somebody might be able to do a man in the middle attack with SSL but then you would get an invalid certificate warning, so you wouldn't continue with the session anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do online banking over a mobile phone connection because there's other possible attacks that aren't specific to the 3G/carrier connection itself.

For example, Bluetooth on many mobile phones can be used for connection sharing with computers, and is not exactly known to be a secure protocol itself.

With the recent release of '[fuzzing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing)' tools for mobile phones, exploitation through SMS may become a common attack vector. See this [Blackhat whitepaper](http://bit.ly/G1Ivd) for more information.

(Note on that paper, a lot of sensationalist coverage focuses on iPhone, but the vulnerabilities are possible on Android and Windows Mobile)